# CSS combine classes, clean code / duplication

Tags: php, css, duplicates

I am creating a CSS cleaner for personal use because the file I have is over 400kb and most the content is duplicated.

I have created a script to read and CSS file and break classes and save there styling in two different arrays.
$css_normal and $classes_by_items_normal

Result of $css_normal (only few items for explanation)

```
Array
(
    [header] => Array
        (
            [display] => block
        )

    [.half-law-first ul] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'Lato', sans-serif
        )

    [.half-law-first ul li a] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'Lato', sans-serif
        )

    [.half-law-second ul li a] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'Lato', sans-serif
        )

    [.half-law-second ul strong] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'Lato', sans-serif
        )

    [.title-blue] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'Lato', sans-serif
        )

    [.enquiry_box_home] => Array
        (
            [min-height] => 480px
        )

    [.will-step1-fbox-footer] => Array
        (
            [padding-top] => 2px
            [padding-bottom] => 20px
            [-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius] => 5px
            [-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius] => 5px
            [-moz-border-radius-bottomleft] => 5px
            [-moz-border-radius-bottomright] => 5px
            [border-bottom-left-radius] => 5px
            [border-bottom-right-radius] => 5px
            [font-family] => 'Lato', sans-serif !important
        )

    [.will-step1-fbox-footer .checkbox ] => Array
        (
            [border-bottom] => 1px dashed #fff
            [padding-bottom] => 8px
            [padding-top] => 2px
        )

    [.second_banner_x] => Array
        (
        )

    [.custom_enquiry_box] => Array
        (
            [width] => 100%
            [height] => auto
            [margin] => 0px
            [padding] => 18px
            [background] => rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.3)
            [color] => #fff
            [position] => relative
            [z-index] => 38
            [margin-top] => 5px
            [-webkit-border-radius] => 5px
            [-moz-border-radius] => 5px
            [border-radius] => 5px
            [box-shadow] => 4px 5px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important
        )
)
```

Result of $classes_by_items_normal (few items for explanation)

```
Array
(
    [display:block] => Array
        (
            [0] => header
            [1] => .enq_a9_result
            [2] => #enq_a9_dots_div
            [3] => .will-intro-box-left h1
            [4] => .will-intro-box-left h1 span
            [5] => .will-intro-box-left h1 span span
            [6] => .will-intro-box-left > h1
            [7] => .wills_2_boxes h1
            [8] => .wills_2_boxes h2.willsBoxH2
            [9] => .wills_2_boxes strong.willsBoxH2
            [10] => .wills_2_boxes b.willsBoxH2
            [11] => strong.WillsH3
            [12] => b.WillsH3
            [13] => .wills_2_will_text_left_area
            [14] => .wills_2_will_text_right_area
            [15] => .nl-banner .tooltip.bottom table td small
            [16] => .aFPPriceAreaLeft .aFPopup + .tooltip.bottom table td small
            [17] => .nl-banner .tooltip.bottom h3 small
            [18] => .aFPPriceAreaLeft .aFPopup + .tooltip.bottom h3 small
            [19] => .will_single_line1
            [20] => .will_single_line2
            [21] => .custom_modal span
            [22] => .login-header-area .s1a
            [23] => .login-header-area .s2a
            [24] => .sign_h2_mobile
            [25] => .show-signup-form
            [26] => .show-signin-form
            [27] => .gform_page_fields
            [28] => .gform_page_footer
            [29] => .account-sidebar li
            [30] => .account-sidebar li a
            [31] => .popup_box_wills_right .heading
            [32] => .popup_box_wills_left .heading
            [33] => .recent-posts-nav li
            [34] => .posts-sidearea2x .will-step1-fbox
            [35] => .difc-posts-right 
            [36] => .wills-video-modal #close_popup_left2
            [37] => .posts-modal #close_popup_left2
            [38] => .inpost-div strong
            [39] => .inpost-div span
            [40] => .wills-play-button-img
            [41] => .not_for_u_b
            [42] => .steps_ans_head
            [43] => .satifaction-form-area strong
            [44] => .satif-testi-area strong
            [45] => .wills-main-banner-area h1
            [46] => .wills-main-banner-area h2
            [47] => .wills-main-banner-area .will-main-left-box p
            [48] => .wills-main-banner-area .will-main-right-box p
            [49] => .wills-main-banner-area .will-main-left-box b
            [50] => .wills-main-banner-area .will-main-right-box b
            [51] => .wills-main-difc span strong
            [52] => .blue-sep3
            [53] => .wills-main-boxes-area1 .main-heading-box
            [54] => .wills-main-boxes-area1 p
            [55] => .wills-main-details-bar p
            [56] => .wills-new-item-price strong 
            [57] => .quest-testi-b
            [58] => .wills-muslim-banner-area h1
            [59] => .wills-muslim-banner-area h2
            [60] => .nl2-banner .inBulletsStrongBig
            [61] => .will-muslim-bottom-box
            [62] => .wills-muslim-banner-area .will-muslim-left-box p
            [63] => .wills-muslim-banner-area .will-muslim-right-box p
            [64] => .wills-muslim-banner-area .will-muslim-bottom-box p
            [65] => .wills-muslim-banner-area .will-muslim-left-box b
            [66] => .wills-muslim-banner-area .will-muslim-right-box b
            [67] => .wills-muslim-banner-area .will-muslim-bottom-box b
            [68] => .wills-muslim-difc span strong
            [69] => .blue-sep3
            [70] => .wills_muslim_mainarea .below_heading p 
            [71] => .dmca-div
            [72] => .dmca-div2
            [73] => .save_quit_div
            [74] => .free-pickup-delivery strong
            [75] => .partners-right-area ul li
            [76] => .partners-right-area ul li strong
            [77] => .partners-right-area ul li em
            [78] => .partners-right-area ul li:after
            [79] => .adptable td span
            [80] => .adptable .btn
            [81] => .adptable .btn:active
            [82] => .adptable .btn:focus
            [83] => .single-feature-homepage .fa-area
            [84] => .single-feature-homepage .text-area
            [85] => .footer 
            [86] => .footer-bottom 
            [87] => .common_p
            [88] => .bullet-inline-price span.crossed
            [89] => .searchStrong
            [90] => .searchoverlay form
            [91] => .searchoverlay2 form
            [92] => .searchMenuButton
            [93] => .searchoverlayClose
            [94] => .searchLink
            [95] => .searchNav
            [96] => .searchNav a
            [97] => .homepage_banner_dropdowns_div_main .dropdowns_area_d
            [98] => .homepage_banner_dropdowns_div_main .dropdowns_area_d.opened
            [99] => .homepage_banner_dropdowns_div_main .dropdowns_area_d .dropdown_name
            [100] => .homepage_banner_dropdowns_div_main .dropdowns_area_d .dropdowns_submenu .dropdown_sub_name
            [101] => .homepage_banner_dropdowns_div_main .dropdowns_area_d .dropdowns_submenu.opened
            [102] => .home_new2_bv_area
            [103] => #posts-youtube-link-banner-home
            [104] => .page-template-legal-forms-all .panel-heading a
            [105] => .allFormsPanelDiv .panel-heading a
            [106] => .page-template-legal-forms-all .panel-body ul
            [107] => .allFormsPanelDiv .aFPRightArea
            [108] => .aFPRightArea .aFPR1_1 strong
            [109] => .aFPRightArea .aFPR1_1 .aFPrice
            [110] => .homepage-tabs-holder ul.nav-tabs li.active>a:after
            [111] => .page-id-3149 .learn-more-area a.scn4 small
            [112] => .pricing-fee-tm
            [113] => .page-id-7527 .will-step1-fbox-footer .tooltip.bottom table td small
            [114] => .page-id-7599 .will-step1-fbox-footer .tooltip.bottom table td small
            [115] => .page-id-3292 .will-step1-fbox-footer .tooltip.bottom table td small
            [116] => .page-id-7527 .will-step1-fbox-footer .tooltip.bottom h3 small
            [117] => .page-id-7599 .will-step1-fbox-footer .tooltip.bottom h3 small
            [118] => .page-id-3292 .will-step1-fbox-footer .tooltip.bottom h3 small
            [119] => .qa-box .panel-title a
            [120] => .headerCurrencyDrop
            [121] => .countrySelect
            [122] => .headerCurrencyDrop.active + ul
            [123] => .countrySelect.active + ul
            [124] => .headerCurrencyDrop + ul > li > a
            [125] => .countrySelect + ul > li > a
            [126] => #mega-menu-wrap-new-header-bar #mega-menu-new-header-bar li.mega-menu-item.mega-menu-item-7731 img
            [127] => #mega-menu-wrap-new-header-bar #mega-menu-new-header-bar li.mega-menu-item.mega-menu-item-7731 span
            [128] => header .login-box a.hiDropdown + ul
            [129] => header .login-box a.hiDropdown.active + ul
            [130] => .btn-3steps-sample
            [131] => .breadcrumbsUL
            [132] => .extra-selectionButton-div
            [133] => .extra-selectionButton-div a
            [134] => .extra-selectionButton-div a small
            [135] => .aFPPriceAreaLeft
            [136] => .aFPSampleAreaRight
            [137] => .aFPopup
            [138] => .aFViewSample
            [139] => .aFPPriceAreaLeft .aFPPriceLeft
            [140] => img.aFPSampleAreaImg
        )

    [font-family:'Lato', sans-serif] => Array
        (
            [0] => .half-law-first ul
            [1] => .half-law-first ul li a
            [2] => .half-law-second ul li a
            [3] => .half-law-second ul strong
            [4] => .title-blue
            [5] => .custom_enquiry_box h1
            [6] => .wills_2_boxes
            [7] => .wills_2_boxes a
            [8] => .accounts-h2
            [9] => .my-accounts-page
            [10] => .popup_box_wills_left
            [11] => .popup_box_wills_right
            [12] => .popup_box_wills_right p
            [13] => .popup_box_wills_left p
            [14] => .popup_box_wills_right li
            [15] => .popup_box_wills_left li
            [16] => .popup_box_wills_right a
            [17] => .popup_box_wills_left a
            [18] => .inpost-div
            [19] => .inpost-div strong
            [20] => .inpost-div span
            [21] => .kcw-banner-box
            [22] => .kcw-banner-box p
            [23] => .kcw-banner-box h1
            [24] => .kcw-banner-box h2
            [25] => .kcw-sep-blue-bar h2
            [26] => .kcw-content-area
            [27] => .kcw-content-area h2
            [28] => .kcw-content-area ul
            [29] => .kcw-content-area ul li
            [30] => .wills-main-banner-area
            [31] => .wills-muslim-banner-area
            [32] => .home_3_boxes .three-boxes-div .single_box
            [33] => .blue-sep h2
            [34] => .intro-home h2
            [35] => header 
            [36] => .sec-row
            [37] => .sec-row .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a
            [38] => .sec-row .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover
            [39] => .sec-row .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:active
            [40] => .nl-price-area2 .colored-bar h3
            [41] => .nl-price-area2 .pricing_content_area h4
        )

    [min-height:480px] => Array
        (
            [0] => .enquiry_box_home
            [1] => .will-intro-box
        )

    [padding-top:2px] => Array
        (
            [0] => .will-step1-fbox-footer
            [1] => .will-step1-fbox-footer .checkbox 
            [2] => .wills-muslim-banner-area
        )

)
```

What I want is to combine classes having same styling
like:

```
header
{
  display: block;
}
.half-law-first ul, .half-law-first ul li a, .half-law-second ul li a, .half-law-second ul strong, .title-blue
{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.enquiry_box_home
{
  min-height: 480px;
}
.will-step1-fbox-footer,
.will-step1-fbox-footer .checkbox 
{
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.will-step1-fbox-footer
{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.will-step1-fbox-footer .checkbox
{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Please let me know how it can be done either with $css_normal or with $classes_by_items_normal via PHP

Thanks.

Comment: Does it has to be PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Loop on $classes_by_items_normal to create an array where the key is the concatenation of all the classes and the value an array of property

this is a non tested code:

```
$newArr = []
forEach($classes_by_items_normal as $prop => $classes){
    newArr[join(',',$classes)][] = $prop
}
```

just loop on $newArr to create the string.

you will have only one property each time instead both property have the exact same classes.

Comment: Thanks for this loop. it does work but classes defined are so many and in this case, classes names (and children in them) are being repeated which is increasing text / file size because for each time it is defining single property.

Answer (score 0):

The following works using a form similar to `$css_normal` but without splitting the properties into key/ value pairs, simply leaving them as strings:

```php
$optimized = [];

foreach (array_keys($css) as $sel) {
  // refetch value since it may have changed during previous iteration
  $def = $css[$sel];

  // find largest common subset
  $subset = [];
  foreach ($css as $s_sel => $s_def) {
    if ($sel === $s_sel) continue;
    $common = array_intersect($def, $s_def);
    if (count($common) > count($subset)) {
      $subset = $common;
    }
  }

  if (empty($subset)) {
    // unchanged
    $optimized[$sel] = $def;
  } else {
    // selectors containing subset
    $sel_concat = [];
    // find & extract subset
    foreach ($css as $s_sel => $s_def) {
      $diff = array_diff($s_def, $subset);
      if (count($s_def) - count($diff) === count($subset)) {
        $sel_concat[] = $s_sel;
        $css[$s_sel] = $diff;
      }
    }
    // concatenate selectors for subset
    $optimized[join(', ', $sel_concat)] = $subset;
  }

}
```

You can try it out [here](https://repl.it/JxOr).

The approach used is to find the largest common subset of CSS properties and grouping them together.

*PS. Could a tool such as [CSSO](https://css.github.io/csso/csso.html) be useful to you rather than rolling out your own solution in PHP?*